# Javascript/CSS from module not loading

Tags: 7, theming

I am using a custom module (copied from a site where it *is* working)

The module's .info file is as follows:

```
name = jCarousel Rotator
description = An image rotator implementing the jCarousel jQuery plugin
package = mymodules
core = 7.x

stylesheets[all][] = css/jcarousel_rotator.css
scripts[] = js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js
scripts[] = js/jcarousel_rotator.js
```

But none of these files are loading.  The theme I'm in is made from scratch.. is there something that needs to be added to the template.php for those include hooks to work?

I searched all the code of the old site and the files are not being explicitly loaded elsewhere.

I have been able to load the files by adding the code manually to the footer, but this is not a great way to have a module integrated.

As requested, my html.tpl.php is as follows:

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<?php echo $page; ?>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: No hooks are required.  They should all work provided that the files exist.  Have you tried clearing your caches?  If you've copied from a working site, are the two sites running the same version of Drupal?

Comment: yep same version.. and I have cleared the cache at least 30 times

Comment: It might sound silly, but is the module enabled on the second site?  Sometimes I forget the simplest things.  Also, is the theme on the first site built from scratch, or does it use a base theme?

Comment: Are those lines first quoted in the MODULE's or the THEME's .info file?  And where are those js/ and css/ directories located?

Comment: module is enabled (I had already doublechecked that worrying that I'd missed that part). the lines are in the module's info file and they are in the module's directory a la `modules/custom/jscarousel/js/jcarousel_rotator.js`

Comment: So you're using the exact same module between sites.  Are you using the same theme?  Perhaps you have custom theme PHP code somewhere that is completely disregarding the generated Drupal header for particular pages?

Comment: Could you paste the whole info file.  Perhaps there's an error somewhere else in the doc that is causing the lines not to be read?

Comment: And this is Drupal 7?  (Drupal 6 doesn't support css and js includes like this)

Comment: yeah it's definitely drupal 7.. I edited my question to include the .info file in its entirety

Comment: So you're writing a theme file from scratch, what files do you have in your templates directory for your theme?  Do you have an html.tpl.php file?  If so, will you post it in it's entirety in your question, please?

Comment: i've edited to include the html.tpl.php !

Comment: That code is not very Drupal-ly at all.  Try switching your theme to Bartik or something and see if the JS/CSS gets added.  FYI, coding it in that - you will almost certainly run into more problems later in in your development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your edit including html.tpl.php, I agree with Chapa that's it very, umm, "Un-Drupaly".  This is the default system rendering of html.tpl.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php print $language->language; ?>" version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" dir="<?php print $language->dir; ?>"<?php print $rdf_namespaces; ?>>

<head profile="<?php print $grddl_profile; ?>">
  <?php print $head; ?>
  <title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
  <?php print $styles; ?>
  <?php print $scripts; ?>
</head>
<body class="<?php print $classes; ?>" <?php print $attributes;?>>
  <div id="skip-link">
    <a href="#main-content" class="element-invisible element-focusable"><?php print t('Skip to main content'); ?></a>
  </div>
  <?php print $page_top; ?>
  <?php print $page; ?>
  <?php print $page_bottom; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

You see where it says:

```
<?php print $styles; ?>
<?php print $scripts; ?>
```

That's where Drupal dumps your JavaScript and CSS files.  If you're not making those calls chances are you're not going to get any included files.  I guess to verify this you'd also have to edit in your header.php and footer.php files so we can see what they contain.  This is where you want to start looking.

I recommend backing up your existing html.tpl.php file to somewhere, and then overwriting it with the system version of it, which can be found at `modules/system/html.tpl.php` relative to the root directory of your site on your system.

Comment: I'm sure Drupal-ly is a word... Maybe I shouldn't have put the hyphen in ;-)

Comment: Add to dictionary... :)

Comment: aha! well we have most of the 'drupal-y' stuff in the header and footer.. thse 2 lines of php should be exactly what I need, though. This way I can print scripts in the footer too where they more properly belong :)

Comment: ps.. i think drupal-y is the adjective.. drupal-ly would be an adverb :p

Comment: You sir, get an upvote :-)

Comment: \(o_O ) / I worked hard for that one.

Answer (score -2):

It will be better if you post the modulename.info file here. As it seems the code in the info file is correct.

About a proper way, If you use hooks then this is what you can do.

drupal_add_css() & drupal_add_js().

```
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name') . '/style.css', array(
    'group' => CSS_DEFAULT, 
    'every_page' => TRUE,
));
```

Then you can call it in hook_init().
Hope that helps you.

Comment: I got bit by this too, and I got down voted for giving this exact same answer.  Reason being is it isn't a solution to the problem he's specified.  The solution should be such that all he needs to do is have the .js and .css files specified in his .info and they should just load on every page.  They're not loading though, so the problem is elsewhere.  Calls to those various API functions are used to load the files on specific pages.

Answer (score -2):

How about adding using `drupal_add_css()` and `drupal_add_js()`. In you .module you can add JS and CSS via `hook_init()`.

Something like this:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook init
 * 
 */
function module_name_init(){
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name') . '/js/module_name.js');
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name').'/css/module_name.css');
}
```